# set bandwidth API purpose

Tags: linux-kernel, dma, trustzone

According to the following change:
[qseecom: Add API to set bandwidth for CE HW](http://visa.lab.asu.edu/gitlab/fstrace/android-kernel-msm-hammerhead-3.4-marshmallow-mr3/commit/57b7b0010886a0268d060b7a78f198c1a2713834)
Want to understand what is CE clk ? What is it responsible for ?

Thanks,